# usage of @attribute with two or more attributes in angular2

Tags: angular

My .ts file includes the code:

```
<reference path="../../../node_modules/angular2/typings/tsd.d.ts" />

import {Component,View,Attribute} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
    selector: 'joint-button',
    inputs: ['btnname,icon']
})
@View({
    templateUrl: 'static/components/button/button.html',
    styleUrls: ['static/components/button/button.css']
})
export class jointbutton{
    button_value: string;
    icon_value: string;
    constructor(@Attribute('btnname') btnname:string, @Attribute('icon') icon:string){
        this.button_value= btnname;
        this.icon_value= icon;
    }
}
```

and the HTML part where i have used this component looks like:

```
<joint-button btnname="First Button" icon="glyphicon glyphicon-home"> </joint-button>
```

My question is how do I use `@Attribute` property with two or more attributes without rewriting the code line again and again for different attributes (as in the export class of Jointbutton). In this case i have used the same line of `@attribute` twice for diff. attributes. I want to use it once but how?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by use it once. But @attribute is annotation that describes the property passed in (metadata). Argument to the constructor needs to specific its metadata independently.

Comment: can i use @attribute('btnname,icon') both in the same attribute. if yes then how ? because if i have to get the propertys of two or more attributes then i have to @attribute.... for each property which is useless i think.

Comment: Use `@attribute('btnname,icon')` like this `@attribute('btnname,icon') btnname:string`?

Comment: not working i have already used this.

Comment: Because that does not mean any sense. @Attribute simply mean map this attribute on html to this property on the component. The mapping is always one to one

Comment: that means i have to use one @attribute for one attribute on html for the component.and there is no way to use multiple attribute in a single '@attribute' ?

Comment: Like @Chandermani said that makes no sense at all. You can instead use `@Input('btnname')` outside the constructor to not contaminate it.

Comment: okay thanks both #chandermani #Eric